# Start Java Application using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: java, powershell

```
$startCount = 5;
$processors = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -
ExpandProperty "NumberOfLogicalProcessors";
$perInstance = $processors / $startCount;
$affinityloop = 1;
$affinityvalue = 0;

for($i=1; $i -le $startCount; $i++) {
   $affinityvalue = 0;
   for($u=1; $u -le $perInstance ; $u++) {
     $affinityvalue = $affinityvalue + $affinityloop;
     $affinityloop = $affinityloop * 2;
   }
   $ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process;
   $ps.StartInfo.Filename = "C:\jdk\bin\java.exe";
   $ps.StartInfo.Arguments = " -server -Xms10240m -Xmx10240m -XX:+UseG1GC -cp `".;*`" Worker";
   $ps.start();
   Write-Host $affinityvalue ;
   $ps.ProcessorAffinity = [Convert]::ToString($affinityvalue, 16);
}
```

I am trying to start a Windows Java application on two different NUMA nodes.  Has anyone able to accomplish this with `Diagnostics.Process` format?  This code does work fine, but all applications created are on the same NUMA node and hence only using 50% power.

I tried codes such as `$mod = ($i % 2);` to help prepare for some way to alternate the NUMA node but unsure how to specify it within the script.

**EDIT**

Tried to load balance with `ProcessorAffinity` and I get crashes due to Double unable to convert to `IntPtr`

**EDIT 2**

So it looks like Windows Groups the processors past 64 into Groups.  Can't seem to find a way to alter that like `ProcessAffinity`.  I guess its just not that common.  You can easily do it in Task manager, just need to find a way to do it in `Powershell` or similar.

Comment: You need to change the `ProcessorAffinity` property to balance the process across different nodes

Comment: Is this post related to "CMD(command prompt, or aka command processor)"

Comment: I attempted to do as you said, but when the values get up with ProcessAffinity (Thread like 50+) I get a double cannot be converted to IntPtr and it crashes.  I tried to convert to binary and same thing occurs.